# Issue with the divisions while importing data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I have been extracting data from different webs with success and had been successful so far but now I am stuck on one website. I have modified my code according to the web and I am new to web scraping.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetListings()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, page As Long, html2 As HTMLDocument
    Dim results As Object, headers(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long

    Const START_PAGE As Long = 0
    Const END_PAGE As Long = 180

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("Name", "Phone", "Address")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For page = START_PAGE To END_PAGE
            .Open "GET", "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=" & page, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set results = html.querySelectorAll(".lemon--ul__-27c0__1_cxs undefined list__373c0__2G8oH")
            Dim output(), r As Long
            ReDim output(1 To results.Length, 1 To 3)
            r = 1
            For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
                On Error Resume Next
                html2.body.innerHTML = results.Item(i).outerHTML
                output(r, 1) = html2.querySelector(".lemon--div__373c0__1mboc businessName__373c0__1fTgn border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT").innerText
                output(r, 2) = html2.querySelector(".lemon--div__373c0__1mboc display--inline-block__373c0__2de_K u-space-b1 border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT").innerText
                'output(r, 3) = html2.querySelector(".track-visit-website").href
                output(r, 3) = html2.querySelector(".lemon--div__373c0__1mboc display--inline-block__373c0__2de_K u-space-b1 border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT").innerText & " " & html2.querySelector(".lemon--div__373c0__1mboc u-space-b1 border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT").innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
                r = r + 1
            Next
            ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)) = output
            page = page + 30
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Problem is highlighted in picture below:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a diffult safety measures at web as well.

Comment: Yes that is also an issue.

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started ?

Comment: No dear, I haven't learned API yet..

Comment: Well you should..It's free and it seems to me that it's easier than what you've been attempting so far. The documentation is extensive and it shows you how to structure a proper request. The response is in JSON format so you'll only need a JSON parser for that.

Comment: Dear can you sort this one out for me so that I could learn by having a sample solution

Comment: You have pasted here the full code without detailing what's going on. Do you think it really helps someone willing to assist you? That said try to clarify in comment Which one is division.  Are you only having trouble parsing division?

Comment: please indicate exactly what the problem is. What is division?

Comment: @QHarr actually I got confused in divisions, however, the below code by SIM is close to what I need, however, the web address & full address is the issue which needs to be sorted & to remove sponsored results

Comment: I sometimes wonder how it would be possible to scrape items from such webpages if there were no such thing as `.querySelector()` because you know when you go for using  calss name or tag name to locate such items it would nearly be impossible @QHarr.

Comment: @SIM As you have seen... since you introduced me to it I depend on it massively.

Comment: What is the issue with  web address & full address  ?

Comment: What you have done so far with `.querySelector()`is second to none in case of vba. I came to know from some your scripts that I can use `.querySelector()` on `.querySelectorAll()` while using a loop in xmlhttp requests method like the way I've tried below.

Comment: web address & full address is in the inner page when you click on Hotel name.

Comment: Ok will take care thanks dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure what you meant by division, I took a guess and wrote a script to serve the purpose. It's really hard to isolate the portion of elements you wanna grab data from. I hardly put my codes between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` but here I dare to as I can see the same within your script. The address block has two different parts. I've handled one. The division (what I've surmised) is upon the address block. So, when you see that the script can't find the address, it will not find the division either. You can handle the address block by defining conditional statement adding `a[href]` within another `.querySelector()` to find the missing addresses.

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start="
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument, page&, I&

    For page = 1 To 2 ' this is where you change the last number for the pages to traverse
        With Http
            .Open "GET", URL & page * 30, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With Html.querySelectorAll("[class*='searchResult']")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .item(I).outerHTML
                On Error Resume Next
                R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='heading--h3'] > a").innerText
                Cells(R, 2) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > [class*='display--inline-block']").innerText
                Cells(R, 3) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > address").innerText
                Cells(R, 4) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > address").NextSibling.innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next I
        End With
    Next page
End Sub
```

Reference to add before running the script:

```
Microsoft Html Object Library
Microsoft xml, v6.0
```

Comment: Thanks, it is close i  need full address like "Pier 39
Ste A-202
San Francisco, CA 94133
Fisherman's Wharf, North Beach/Telegraph Hill" & web address field like "fogharbor.com" for the first data as we click on restaurant name window opens and from there you can find it. Moreover need to remove those sponsored results, rest is great.

Comment: @SIM great technique, web address would be the icing on the cake.

Comment: Thanks @M Faizan Farooq.

Comment: @SIM you got any technique to extract remaining fields

Comment: To get all the fields like the way you want, you should go one layer deep using the links of each items from it's landing page. When you are on the innerpage of each poducts , you can find them very easy to scrape.

Comment: @SIM and how to remove sponsored results?

Comment: Did you mean those vicious ads?

Comment: Yes like in scrapped data first 3 are sponsored results data.

Comment: They are ready to be kicked out. Currently the site has blocked me. I'll let you know once I can acess it again.

Answer (score 0):

Partly solved the problem

Here is the modified code. In some cases it is still failing to fetch Address

```
Set results = html.getElementsByClassName("lemon--div__373c0__1mboc largerScrollablePhotos__373c0__3FEIJ arrange__373c0__UHqhV border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT")
            Debug.Print results.Length
            Dim output(), r As Long
            ReDim output(1 To results.Length, 1 To 3)
            r = 1
            For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
                'On Error Resume Next
                html2.body.innerHTML = results.Item(i).innerHTML
                output(r, 1) = html2.getElementsByClassName("lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__29943 link-color--blue-dark__373c0__1mhJo link-size--inherit__373c0__2JXk5")(0).innerText
                output(r, 2) = html2.getElementsByClassName("lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--right__373c0__3ARv7")(0).innerText
                output(r, 3) = html2.getElementsByClassName("lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--right__373c0__3ARv7")(1).innerText
                'On Error GoTo 0
                r = r + 1
            Next
            ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)) = output
```

better to run the script without turning screen updating off as it takes a hell of time to bring even a single page.